# FFmpeg pass arguments in a text file

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get around the 32767 characters limit regarding the command line length in Windows (sometimes it's less than that). I have a large number of boxes that I'm trying to draw on a video. Typically I can concatenate the draw commands using a comma (`,`) like so (the following command draws two boxes):

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf "drawbox=enable='between(t, 1.5, 4)' : x=100 : y=100 : w=200 : h=200 : color=green,drawbox=enable='between(t, 9, 18)' : x=500 : y=10 : w=150 : h=150 : color=red" -codec:a copy output.mp4
```

However since I have many boxes to draw, the length of the entire command becomes too large.

Does FFmpeg offer a way to pass all arguments in a text file instead of literal text? Something like this:

```
ffmpeg content(ffmpegCmd.txt)
```

If that's not possible, is it possible to "buffer" the arguments into separate commands while exporting the result only in the last command?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does FFmpeg offer a way to pass all arguments in a text file instead of literal text?

Use the `-filter_complex_script` option. From the [documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html):

> `-filter_complex_script filename` (global)
>
> This option is similar to -filter_complex, the only difference is that its argument is the name of the file from which a complex filtergraph description is to be read.

Basic example:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex_script filters.txt output
```

Comment: It turns out that the `drawbox` command is supported by `filter_complex_script` and not `filter_script` in this context. I modified your answer accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: Just adding a note that caught me out on this.  Prior to discovering the `filter_complex_script` option (it changed my life! -sniff.) I had been constructing the filter graphs by building a string using environment variables and batch.  There seems to be a limit of 8k characters or so on the length of an environment variable.  I spent some time chasing this thinking the limit was coming from `FFMpeg`, whereas it was actually `CMD` that was causing the batch file to fail.

Answer (score 0):

-filter_complex_script filename doesn't work. For example:

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -codec copy 1.mp4
```

works fine.

Next I place -codec copy to filters.txt and try

```
ffmpeg -i 1.mkv -filter_complex_script filters.txt 1.mp4
```

It gives me the error: No such filter -codec copy